# jQuery IF statement that finds all inputs with null values and removes corresponding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm attempting to create a jQuery script that works something like this: Check all inputs to see if their field is empty (null). If it is empty go to the next occurring span (sibling element), find its child image contained within the span and remove it. This is what I have so far.

```
if ($("input").val() == "") {
$(this).next("span").find("img:first").remove();
}
```

I broke it apart and tried to run just the inner code within console with slight modification. I aimed just to delete the img.

```
$("input").next("span").find("img:first").remove();
```

Could never get it to work. Technically, there is only ever one img within the span but I left it on just for kicks.

Any idea how to first get my isolated line of code to work, then incorporate it into that IF statement? Also, am I making correct use of ***(this)***? Thanks.

***HTML of form per request:***

```
<div class="voucher-input first-input">
   Voucher 1: <input style="text-transform: uppercase;" maxlength="20" name="voucher1" id="voucher1" title="Voucher" class="input" value="" type="text"><span id="voucher1dbpass" style="position: absolute; right: 5%;"><img src="valid.png" width="30" height="30"> </span>
   <span class="vouchererr" id="1">Remove Any Illegal Characters</span>

    <span class="error"></span>
    </div>

<div class="voucher-input second-input">
   Voucher 2: <input style="text-transform: uppercase;" maxlength="20" name="voucher2" id="voucher2" title="Voucher" class="input" value="" type="text"><span id="voucher2dbpass" style="position: absolute; right: 5%;"><img src="invalid.png" width="30" height="30"><br> </span>
   <span class="vouchererr" id="2">Remove Any Illegal Characters</span>

   <span class="error"></span>
```

***Background:*** I have a number of vouchers fields in a form. AJAX is checking the DB to see if supplied voucher numbers are good or bad. If they are good, they get a check (valid.png). If bad, they get an X (invalid.png). Because of how my AJAX/PHP interacts, the img element is loaded from a separate PHP file. If a user removes their valid or invalid entry from the voucher field, I would then need to use the .remove() function to delete it from the form. In normal form validation methods, using something like .hide()/.show() would be enough but the "original state" of this element was non-existent.

So then, instead of doing individual IF statements for each, I would rather just use some sort of "dynamic" method that uses element patterns instead of redundancies.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I think works, but your problem description is *incredibly* vague: could you add context? HTML would be useful. on what occasion/event should this code run?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance David. I have provided HTML as requested. Let me know if I can provide anything else. Also, tried the solution below but as you mentioned, I needed to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Given your problem description:

```
$('input').filter(function () {
    return !this.value.trim().length
}).next('span').find('img').remove();
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).